# Substitute an unevaluated argument into multiple functions

Tags: r

Consider the following function `foo`.  I'd like to hard-code `na.rm = TRUE` into each of the calls in the list that returns the result, but I only want to write it once.  My current implementation does not work.

```
foo <- function(x) {
    e <- expression(na.rm = TRUE)
    list(sum(x, eval(e)), mean(x, eval(e)), sd(x, eval(e)))
}
```

I **do not** want to use `...` in the argument list for this function.  I don't want to give the user the option to add an `na.rm` argument.  The problem with the above code is that

```
> eval(expression(na.rm = TRUE))
# [1] TRUE
```

and therefore the `TRUE` is passed to the `trim` argument in `mean`, instead of `na.rm`

```
> foo(c(1, NA, 3))
# Error in mean.default(x, eval(e)) : 'trim' must be numeric of length one
```

Is there a way to pass the argument as an expression, perhaps with `quote` or `substitute`, so that R would read the argument as `na.rm = TRUE` instead of just `TRUE` ?

**Note:**  My actual function is using `quiet = TRUE` five times in seven lines, so the code would be cleaner if I could just write the expression once, and pass it to each of the five functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know whether this is a good idea in any case, but what you want to do can be done with `do.call` :

```
foo <- function(x) {
  args <- list(quote(x),na.rm=TRUE)
  list(
    do.call(sum,args), 
    do.call(mean, args),
    do.call(sd, args)
  )
}
```

As Hadley said in the comments, you don't want to copy `x` completely in the list `args`, as that can give memory problems when `x` is big. Hence the use of `quote()` (thx Hadley)

This gives:

```
> foo(c(1, NA, 3))
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 1.414214
```

Comment: I'm noticing lately that when you need to do something with  arguments, it's all about `do.call`.

Comment: @RichardScriven That's because do.call takes the arguments as a list, and lists are more easy to manipulate than expressions and language elements. do.call is made for it, so pretty obvious that it's all about do.call I'd say :)

Comment: Beware that this solution copies `x` and inserts a literal copy of `x` into the call (which if large will make `traceback()` very slow on errors`). It would be better to do `args <- list(quote(x), na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude the `NA`s before using the functions:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    x2 <- na.omit(x)
    list(sum(x2), mean(x2), sd(x2))
}
```

Another possibility is to use `lapply` with the functions you want to use:

```
foo <- function(x) {
   lapply(c(sum, mean, sd), function(f) f(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, yes. But not for the general case and definitely not when the actual function is using `quiet = TRUE` as OP states in his note.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
    lapply(c(sum, mean, sd), do.call, list(x, na.rm=TRUE))
}

fun1(c(1,NA,3))
#[[1]]
#[1] 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 1.414214
```